# Initial load speed-wise, how do server side templates compare against client side ones for single page apps

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

For a single page app, how I figure you go about templating server side is you basically load all the pages as hidden on initial load except the index, and switch between pages by hiding/unhiding, or translating, or whatever approach you take.
Whereas if you template client-side, then you have all the pages loaded as script files and you render them into html when they're needed.
Based on these techniques, my impression is that the client-side templating would be faster for the initial load since it just downloads the scripts instead of parsing them, then offsets the parsing for later. Is this right?
Are there other, better ways of doing it so that your initial load time is shorter?

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to what you think is a better user experience.  If you load all content up front, then the transitions when changing "pages" will typically be a lot smoother.  If you use AJAX to load additional "pages", then obviously the might be a bit of a lag when doing page transitions, depending on size of content and server load.

If your total content is really small, you might be better loading it all up front, whereas if the total content is sizable, loading it on an as-needed basis is usually better.

Comment: Mm the approach I was thinking of for client-side wasn't AJAXing in the additional pages. I agree that wouldn't be very smooth for the transitions. What I mean is loading them up front as well, but in the template script tags, like <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">template content</script> and then just parsing on page transition. Would that be faster or slower?